# How to Map IP to IP in etc/hosts

Tags: windows, ip, domain, hosts

I know that in C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts I can map IP to domain name like this
`127.0.0.1       whatever.com`
however when I tried to map to a different IP it doesn't work. For example
`127.0.0.1       99.99.99.99`

Could anyone help please?

Thanks

Comment: You have it backwards. The hosts file (like DNS on a larger scale) maps domain name to IPaddress. It is only used when a program has a domain name and needs the corresponding address. If a program already has an address, it doesn't lookup that address, not in the hosts file or anywhere else. If you ask a question about whatever it is that you are actually trying to do, there may be a solution, but not by mapping an address.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and why?